# Retrieving Large Data from MySql C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms, dataadapter

I am retrieving Data from MySql (Xampp PhpMyAdmin) using C# Windows forms. I using Data Adapter and data tables to retrieve it but the dta is like around 4 million records 4014835 total
When am retrieving like a thousand records  its good like taking 3 or 4 seconds 
But when i go for A hundred thousand 100,000 its takes 2 or 1 minute
Is there any better approach ?

Comment: end of query would be `... LIMIT offset,pageSize` for pagination

Comment: is there any other way to retrieve data rather than data adapters or data readers ?

Comment: It is not practical to retrieve all the records, It is better to retrieve smaller subsets of it by paging through the query result.

Comment: Thanks People that was useful

Comment: @ahsan I write pretty much exclusively c# and mysql. I don't use datatables and adapters at all. I use memory. Sometimes `List<myThing>` and more often than not I don't even use that, just jam stuff into the datagridview.

Comment: I might suggest also enabling a search feature. Even with paging the result set is way too big to be useful.

Comment: Like a million rows in master, bring back a default of 80 rows at a time. Allow the user to modify the `pageSize` via the GUI. Fast as all get up. I have one pointing at a well indexed student database that has 30 million rows.

Comment: @Drew by " jam stuff into the datagridview." what do you mean ?

Comment: You really should stick to one question at a time, but you can use ADO.Net or some ORM like Entity Framework, Dapper, NHibernate(shiver), etc.

Comment: From what hear, using EF with mysql is painful. As for orms, ugh, in general. Everyone has their favorite pair of sneakers. Mine is performance.

Comment: At this point avoiding ORMs is kind of like avoiding languages that manage memory for you. They represent a higher level of abstraction that improves productivity and the technology is quite mature now.

Comment: @Drew, how do you get data out of MySql without any data access technology at all?

Comment: Then there are the guys using orms who are stuck in its glue and can't get it to work. Then they come to us for `raw` queries to break out of the penalty box.

Comment: @Crowcoder I said to him that I don't use datatables and adapters. I use memory slots, sometimes the List<>, or right into the grid. Like my interface I built for using the stack [here](http://i.imgur.com/FxWWkDK.jpg)